# Processing guess(float[]) does not exist even though it's been declared

Tags: java, processing

I was using processing and I was learning by a tutorial, but I ran into a problem while scripting

**Code**
Perceptron

```
Perceptron p;
void setup(){
 size(200,200); 
 p = new Perceptron();
 float[] inputs = {-1,0.5};
 int guess = p.guess(inputs);
 println(guess);
}

void draw(){

}
```

CC_SimplePerceptron

```
// Activation function
int sign(float n){
  if (n >= 0){
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
   return -1; 
  }
}
class Perceptronn {
  float[] weights = new float[2];

  //Constructor
  void Perceptron(){
    //Initializes weights randomly
    for(int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++){
      weights[i] = random(-1,1);
    }
  }

  int guess(float[] inputs){
    float sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i< weights.length; i++) {
      sum += inputs[i] * weights[i];
    }
    int output = sign(sum);
    return output;
  }
}
```

I was learning off of Coding train's tutorial on how to make machine learning, but I think it may also have to do with that I'm using processing and he's probably either using Processing himself or using sketch.js

Comment: `class Perceptronn` is that extra `n` in your code?

Comment: I had to use an extra n to make it work since there would be 2 classes of the same name, or are you talking about the first script?

Comment: Actually thank you, I just needed to add a variable for the “Perceptionn” class, but now it’s saying that it there is a NullPointerException error displaying when I’m running it

Comment: `void Perceptron()` is not a constructor. And it's doubly not a constructor for a `Perceptionn` class. It shouldn't be `void`. And the name should match the class name. Having two classes with such similar names is a "code smell". Please edit your question. Tell us where the exception happens. Although, once you say it's a NullPointerException the question will be closed as a duplicate (lots of NullPointerException questions on the site).

Comment: The code you posted does not reproduce the bugs you're talking about. Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates your actual problem. Also, please ask follow-up questions in their own posts.